# Problemas layouts multipantallas android

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo ya unos dias probando los layouts de mi app con todos los emuladores. Mi acitivity tiene un videoview y el titulo de video debajo del videoview.Mas otra informacion debajo del titulo. Con el siguiente codigo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.app.videos.app.Views.reproductorActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_include"
        />



</LinearLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout5">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

        <videoView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/videoView" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

            <LinearLayout

                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:foregroundTint="#090909">



                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="Titulo del video"
                    android:id="@+id/textView_titulo"
                    android:autoText="true"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_dark"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_icon_size"
                    android:textColorLink="#030303" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="20px"
                    android:layout_height="20px" />


                <Space
                    android:layout_width="20px"
                    android:layout_height="20px" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout9">
                    <GridView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="360dp"
                        android:id="@+id/ListView_listado"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:numColumns="2"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"/>


                </FrameLayout>





            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Esto lo probe con todos los emuladores en cada una de las dimensiones disponibles y en algunos el titulo se veia mas separado del video que en otros emuladores mas pequeños. El gran problema es que lo probe en un celular Lg 9 Optimus y el resultado es espantoso. El titulo del video se ve encima del video y parte del grid view tambien se ve encima del video.
Que tengo que hacer entonces para que mis layouts se vean bien en todas la pantallas??? Como ya he explicado lo tengo programado en todas las dimensiones disponibles

Comment: quiza la documentación oficial te ayude https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que en tu layout estas definiendo usar pixeles en algunos widgets, lo cual se ve afectado cuando cargas tu aplicación en **dispositivos de diferentes densidades**, en algunos se podrá mostrar correctamente la UI de tu aplicación pero en otros se desplegaría incorrectamente, te recomiendo usar [Density-independent pixels](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) (dp).

> [Density-independent pixels](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html): Una unidad de píxel virtual que se
>   debe utilizar cuando se define el diseño de interfaz de usuario, para
>   expresar las dimensiones o la posición del layout de una manera
>   independiente de la densidad.

Comment: Lo he cambiado todo a dp. Como me has sugerido.. Pero aun asi no se ve igual en todas las pantallas con la dimension correspondiente... Por ejemplo aun con el cambio en  ninguna de las pantallas que tengan las mismas dimensiones se ve igual...Lo mismo pasa si lo trabajo con los tamaños en ves de con las dimensiones

Comment: Eduardo podrías agregar una imagen donde se vea la diferencia?